# Is it possible to modify the UI of a Drupal Module?

Tags: drupal, user-interface, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am working on a project where we have found a module that suits our needs (FileDepot, https://drupal.org/project/filedepot), but would like to change the look and feel of it. I am new to using Drupal, so I am not sure if it is even possible/practical to change the UI of an installed module. Can anyone offer some insight on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can change anything with the drupal theme and CSS. You can even change the admin panel theme if you want to.

To change a theme you can find a drupal guide here:

http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-make-a-drupal-theme